# How to keep products in basket for multiple month?

Tags: redis, sessions

how can we keep the chosen products in the basket for multiple month?
We are using Magento 1.9 with redis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on the `persistent cart` under `System > Configuration > Persistent Shopping Cart` and make sure the `Quote Lifetime` if sufficiently high under `System > Configuraton > Checkout > Shopping cart`

That should give your customers their cart back when they return